# Error submitting setKeys function in POA chain using polkadotJS

Tags: validator, poa, validator-set

PolkadotJS version 0.9.30

[image]

Im following following tutorial https://github.com/gautamdhameja/substrate-validator-set/blob/polkadot-v0.9.30/docs/council-integration.md and getting  the following error when submitting keys

How to fix this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears to me that the output from rotatekeys shouldsplit in to half

The first 64bits are the correct key