# How to configure collective pallet with a Proof of authority chain with scheduler and preimage pallet

Tags: pallet-collective

Code

```
parameter_types! {
    pub const CouncilMotionDuration: BlockNumber = 3 * MINUTES;
    pub const CouncilMaxProposals: u32 = 100;
    pub const CouncilMaxMembers: u32 = 100;
}

type TechnicalCollective = pallet_collective::Instance1;

impl pallet_collective::Config<TechnicalCollective> for Runtime {
    type RuntimeOrigin = RuntimeOrigin;
    type Proposal = RuntimeCall;
    type RuntimeEvent = RuntimeEvent;
    type MotionDuration = CouncilMotionDuration;
    type MaxProposals = CouncilMaxProposals;
    type MaxMembers = CouncilMaxMembers;
    type DefaultVote = pallet_collective::PrimeDefaultVote;
    type WeightInfo = pallet_collective::weights::SubstrateWeight<Runtime>;
}

type EnsureRootOrHalfCouncil = EitherOfDiverse<
    EnsureRoot<AccountId>,
    pallet_collective::EnsureProportionMoreThan<AccountId, TechnicalCollective, 1, 2>,
>;

impl pallet_validator_set::Config for Runtime {
    type RuntimeEvent = RuntimeEvent;
    // see readme for type declaration
    type AddRemoveOrigin = EnsureRootOrHalfCouncil;
    type MinAuthorities = MinAuthorities;
}
```

Im looking a documentation where it explains how to use governance with a POa based chain , how to configure scheduling here?>

The Issue

- How to execute an extrinsic with a custom origin with a given blocknumber after voting approval ?
- Cannot see validators are rotating after an epoch

How to configure those ?

Comment: What is the issue here? Please clarify your question. If you want to configure the collective pallet you can look [here](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/71d749c74e43c7a840c94fcbbdd2b0172a21d473/bin/node/runtime/src/lib.rs#L999-L1017). If you want to configure the scheduler pallet you can look [here](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/71d749c74e43c7a840c94fcbbdd2b0172a21d473/bin/node/runtime/src/lib.rs#L356-L375)

Comment: added more context, thank you

Comment: Please include the Github link to your repo.

Comment: @Bruno still the project is on private mode due to management decisions , thank you

Comment: @Bruno I have ended up with this error https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/7785/error-submitting-setkeys-function-in-poa-chain-using-polkadotjs when trying to submit keys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to execute an extrinsic with a custom origin with a given blocknumber after voting approval?

Use the scheduler pallet with the preimage pallet or you can use the scheduler pallet with the utility pallet's dispatchAs extrinsic.

> Cannot see validators are rotating after an epoch

Make sure you have the validator-set pallet and the session pallet properly configured:

- https://github.com/gautamdhameja/substrate-validator-set#pallet-initialization---runtimesrclibrs

Comment: will there be an example or a document on this 

Use the scheduler pallet with the preimage pallet or you can use the scheduler pallet with the utility pallet's dispatchAs extrinsic.

Comment: There is an old one [here](https://www.youtube.com/live/sT0HaQRD-FU?feature=share&t=1468). There is also one solely on the scheduler pallet [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=olcuZHb4u88). There is also a section on the Polkadot wiki [here](https://wiki.polkadot.network/docs/maintain-guides-democracy#submitting-a-preimage). Moonbeam also has a good doc [here](https://docs.moonbeam.network/tokens/governance/proposals/proposals/#submitting-a-preimage-of-the-proposal).